# Show hide multiple divs based on select value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select

Looking for some jQuery to help hide and reveal content in a simple form I'm creating.

Picking options 1-3 in the select field should show one of the three data response divs as well as reveal the content in the rest of the form (data-form-order 2).

I think data attributes would be a good route to go down but a little unsure of where to start.

```
<form>
  <div data-form-order="1">

    <div id="opening-question">
      <select id="select-box">
      <option value="0">- please select -</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div data-response="op1">
      This is content for option 1.
    </div>
    <div data-response="op2">
      This is content for option 2.
    </div>
    <div data-response="op3">
      This is content for option 3.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-form-order="2" id="other-questions">
    Rest of form content. This area should show when option values 1-3 are selected in the select field.
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Really all you need is to hide all the divs using some CSS by default, and then use the `change` function to get the value and select the div based on that value:

```js
$('#select-box').change(function(){

   var selectVal = $(this).val();
   $('.content, #other-questions').hide();
   $('.content[data-response="op' + selectVal + '"], #other-questions').show();

});
```

```css
.content, #other-questions {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div data-form-order="1">

    <div id="opening-question">
      <select id="select-box">
      <option value="0">- please select -</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="content" data-response="op1">
      This is content for option 1.
    </div>
    <div class="content" data-response="op2">
      This is content for option 2.
    </div>
    <div class="content" data-response="op3">
      This is content for option 3.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-form-order="2" id="other-questions">
    Rest of form content. This area should show when option values 1-3 are selected in the select field.
  </div>
</form>
```

I've updated my answer to include classes which are better for selecting elements than data attributes.

Comment: This potentially looks like a clean solution but it's showing the "other-questions" div from the outset. This div should only appear when options 1-3 are selected.

Comment: @okass I've updated my answer to to include this too :).

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend reading [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).  You can make some really simple and reusable jQuery that does some pretty cool stuff, without a lot of duplicate code or tightly coupled code.  The following is very extensible, reusable, easy to read and maintain.

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
  $('.js-revealer').on('change', function(){
    var $select = $(this);
    var $selected = $select.find('option:selected');
    var hideSelector = $selected.data('r-hide-target');
    var showSelector = $selected.data('r-show-target');
    
    $(hideSelector).addClass('is-hidden');
    $(showSelector).removeClass('is-hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.is-hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div data-form-order="1">

    <div id="opening-question">
      <select id="select-box" class="js-revealer">
      <option value="0" data-r-show-target="" data-r-hide-target=".opt-1, .opt-2, .opt-3, .opt-other">- please select -</option>
      <option value="1" data-r-show-target=".opt-1, .opt-other" data-r-hide-target=".opt-2, .opt-3">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2" data-r-show-target=".opt-2, .opt-other" data-r-hide-target=".opt-1, .opt-3">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3" data-r-show-target=".opt-3, .opt-other" data-r-hide-target=".opt-1, .opt-2">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div data-response="op1" class="opt-1 is-hidden">
      This is content for option 1.
    </div>
    <div data-response="op2" class="opt-2 is-hidden">
      This is content for option 2.
    </div>
    <div data-response="op3" class="opt-3 is-hidden">
      This is content for option 3.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-form-order="2" id="other-questions" class="opt-other is-hidden">
    Rest of form content. This area should show when option values 1-3 are selected in the select field.
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you clarify the second half of the .ready line? Why did you put in =>?

Comment: It's an [Arrow Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Ah I see. This article explains it better I think: https://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/01/a-guide-to-es6-arrow-functions/

Comment: Just a word of warning that it looks like the arrow function expression doesn't work in IE11 and older versions of Safari

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using classes for this, there is no need for data attributes.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#select-box').change(function(){
        if($('#select-box').val() == '1') {
            $('.response1').show();
            $('.response2').hide();
            $('.response3').hide();
            $('#content').show();
        } 
        else if($('#select-box').val() == '2') {
            $('.response1').hide();
            $('.response2').show();
            $('.response3').hide();
            $('#content').show();
        }
        else if($('#select-box').val() == '3') {
            $('.response1').hide();
            $('.response2').hide();
            $('.response3').show();
            $('#content').show();
        } 
    });
});
```

```css
.response1, .response2, .response3 {
  display: none;
}

#content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div data-form-order="1">

    <div id="opening-question">
      <select id="select-box">
      <option value="0">- please select -</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class='response1' data-response="op1">
      This is content for option 1.
    </div>
    <div class='response2' data-response="op2">
      This is content for option 2.
    </div>
    <div class='response3' data-response="op3">
      This is content for option 3.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id='content' data-form-order="2" id="other-questions">
    Rest of form content. This area should show when option values 1-3 are selected in the select field.
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have shown show/hide using `Class` . Initially hide all div's , shown on drop down selection (only matches div).Here is how.I have created two classes `hide`
to hide the element and `show` to show the element.

```js
$('[data-response^=op]').attr('class',"hide");//Initially set all div hidden
$("#select-box").on("change",function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  if(value !="" && value<=3 && value !=0){
    console.clear();// to clear older logs.
    console.log('Selected value'+$(this).val());
    $('[data-response^=op]').attr('class',"hide");//On change hide all div's
    var selector = "op"+value;
    $(document).find("[data-response='"+selector+"']").attr('class',"show");
    $("#other-questions").attr('class',"show");//Show matching div.
  }else{
   $("#other-questions").attr('class',"hide");
   $('[data-response^=op]').attr('class',"hide");
  }

})
```

```css
.hide{
display:none;
}

.show{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div data-form-order="1">

    <div id="opening-question">
      <select id="select-box">
      <option value="0">- please select -</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div data-response="op1">
      This is content for option 1.
    </div>
    <div data-response="op2">
      This is content for option 2.
    </div>
    <div data-response="op3">
      This is content for option 3.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-form-order="2" id="other-questions" class="hide">
    Rest of form content. This area should show when option values 1-3 are selected in the select field.
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like a good solution although when the user goes back to option 0 ("please select") the "other questions" div is still showing. How can I account for this?