# Show/hide multiple divs based on dropdown selection Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a form that will show more fields based on what is selected in a dropdown menu. If 1 guest is selected, then 1 form appears. If 2, then 2 forms appears and so on.

I've managed to get the first Div (guestFormOne) to show/hide depending if 1 guest has been selected, but I'm struggling to find a solution to make this happen for up to 6 guests.

Here is what I have so far:

HTML

```
    <h4>Number of Guests</h4>
<select onchange="numofGuests()">
  <option>Select number of guests</option>
  <option id="guestCountOne">1</option>
  <option id="guestCountTwo">2</option>
  <option id="guestCountThree">3</option>
  <option id="guestCountFour">4</option>
  <option id="guestCountFive">5</option>
  <option id="guestCountSix">6</option>
</select>

<div id="guestFormOne">
  <h4>Guest 1</h4>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
  <select id="guest1_meal">
   <option>Meal Choice</option>
   <option>Buffet</option>
   <option>Gluten Free</option>
   <option>Dairy Free</option>
   <option>Vegan</option>
  </select>

  <select id="guest1_age">
   <option>Age</option>
   <option>Adult</option>
   <option>Child under 5</option>
   <option>Child 6 - 12</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Allergies?">
</div>

<div id="guestFormTwo">
  <h4>Guest 2</h4>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
  <select id="guest2_meal">
   <option>Meal Choice</option>
   <option>Buffet</option>
   <option>Gluten Free</option>
   <option>Dairy Free</option>
   <option>Vegan</option>
  </select>

  <select id="guest2_age">
   <option>Age</option>
   <option>Adult</option>
   <option>Child under 5</option>
   <option>Child 6 - 12</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Allergies?">
</div>
```

Javascript

```
   function numofGuests() {
      if (document.getElementById("guestCountOne").selected) {
        document.getElementById("guestFormOne").style.display = "block";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("guestFormOne").style.display = "none";
      }
    }
```

Help would be appreciated, as I feel like I'm stuck trying to get this to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show hide multiple divs based on select value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675930/show-hide-multiple-divs-based-on-select-value)

Comment: @Jdar : Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add as many as you want, dynamically:

```js
function numofGuests(val) {
    document.getElementById('guestFormOne').innerHTML = "";
    for (i = 0; i < parseInt(val.value); i++) { 
        document.getElementById('guestFormOne').innerHTML += '<h4>Guest '+(i+1)+'</h4><input type="text" placeholder="Name"><select  id="guest'+(i+1)+'_meal"><option>Meal Choice</option> <option>Buffet</option><option>Gluten Free</option><option>Dairy Free</option><option>Vegan</option></select><select id="guest'+(i+1)+'_age"><option>Age</option><option>Adult</option><option>Child under 5</option><option>Child 6 - 12</option></select><input type="text" placeholder="Allergies?">';
    }      
}
```

```html
<h4>Number of Guests</h4>
<select onchange="numofGuests(this)">
  <option>Select number of guests</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
</select>

<div id="guestFormOne"></div>
```

Comment: The question was not tagged with JQuery.

Comment: Ok, but there is a little difference, only a bit more code needs. I will update the code.

Answer (score 0):

You would get all the hidden guest forms into a collection and then loop through that collection, unhiding them until you reach the count selected in the drop down. The guest forms don't need `id`s, you would just give them all the same CSS class. You would also set all of the guest forms to be hidden by default (using CSS a class as well, rather than with inline styles).

Lastly, don't use inline HTML event attributes (`onchange`, `onclick`, etc.). This is an ancient technique that **[causes many problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)** and needs to just die. Instead, do all your event binding in JavaScript.

```js
var guestCount = document.getElementById("guestCount");
guestCount.addEventListener("change", numOfGuests);

// Get all the guest forms into an collection
var guestForms = document.querySelectorAll(".guestForm");


function numOfGuests() {
  // Loop through the guest forms based on the number selected
  guestForms.forEach(function(v,i){
    if(i < guestCount.value) {
      v.classList.remove("hidden");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<h4>Number of Guests</h4>
<select id="guestCount">
  <option>Select number of guests</option>
  <option id="guestCountOne">1</option>
  <option id="guestCountTwo">2</option>
  <option id="guestCountThree">3</option>
  <option id="guestCountFour">4</option>
  <option id="guestCountFive">5</option>
  <option id="guestCountSix">6</option>
</select>

<div class="guestForm hidden">
  <h4>Guest 1</h4>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
  <select id="guest1_meal">
   <option>Meal Choice</option>
   <option>Buffet</option>
   <option>Gluten Free</option>
   <option>Dairy Free</option>
   <option>Vegan</option>
  </select>

  <select id="guest1_age">
   <option>Age</option>
   <option>Adult</option>
   <option>Child under 5</option>
   <option>Child 6 - 12</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Allergies?">
</div>

<div class="guestForm hidden">
  <h4>Guest 2</h4>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
  <select id="guest2_meal">
   <option>Meal Choice</option>
   <option>Buffet</option>
   <option>Gluten Free</option>
   <option>Dairy Free</option>
   <option>Vegan</option>
  </select>

  <select id="guest2_age">
   <option>Age</option>
   <option>Adult</option>
   <option>Child under 5</option>
   <option>Child 6 - 12</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Allergies?">
</div>

<div class="guestForm hidden">
  <h4>Guest 3</h4>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
  <select id="guest2_meal">
   <option>Meal Choice</option>
   <option>Buffet</option>
   <option>Gluten Free</option>
   <option>Dairy Free</option>
   <option>Vegan</option>
  </select>

  <select id="guest2_age">
   <option>Age</option>
   <option>Adult</option>
   <option>Child under 5</option>
   <option>Child 6 - 12</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Allergies?">
</div>

<div class="guestForm hidden">
  <h4>Guest 4</h4>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
  <select id="guest2_meal">
   <option>Meal Choice</option>
   <option>Buffet</option>
   <option>Gluten Free</option>
   <option>Dairy Free</option>
   <option>Vegan</option>
  </select>

  <select id="guest2_age">
   <option>Age</option>
   <option>Adult</option>
   <option>Child under 5</option>
   <option>Child 6 - 12</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Allergies?">
</div>

<div class="guestForm hidden">
  <h4>Guest 5</h4>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
  <select id="guest2_meal">
   <option>Meal Choice</option>
   <option>Buffet</option>
   <option>Gluten Free</option>
   <option>Dairy Free</option>
   <option>Vegan</option>
  </select>

  <select id="guest2_age">
   <option>Age</option>
   <option>Adult</option>
   <option>Child under 5</option>
   <option>Child 6 - 12</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Allergies?">
</div>

<div class="guestForm hidden">
  <h4>Guest 6</h4>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
  <select id="guest2_meal">
   <option>Meal Choice</option>
   <option>Buffet</option>
   <option>Gluten Free</option>
   <option>Dairy Free</option>
   <option>Vegan</option>
  </select>

  <select id="guest2_age">
   <option>Age</option>
   <option>Adult</option>
   <option>Child under 5</option>
   <option>Child 6 - 12</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Allergies?">
</div>

<div class="guestForm hidden">
  <h4>Guest 2</h4>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
  <select id="guest2_meal">
   <option>Meal Choice</option>
   <option>Buffet</option>
   <option>Gluten Free</option>
   <option>Dairy Free</option>
   <option>Vegan</option>
  </select>

  <select id="guest2_age">
   <option>Age</option>
   <option>Adult</option>
   <option>Child under 5</option>
   <option>Child 6 - 12</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Allergies?">
</div>

<div class="guestForm hidden">
  <h4>Guest 2</h4>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
  <select id="guest2_meal">
   <option>Meal Choice</option>
   <option>Buffet</option>
   <option>Gluten Free</option>
   <option>Dairy Free</option>
   <option>Vegan</option>
  </select>

  <select id="guest2_age">
   <option>Age</option>
   <option>Adult</option>
   <option>Child under 5</option>
   <option>Child 6 - 12</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Allergies?">
</div>
```

Now, having shown all that, really the best solution is to just dynamically create the guest forms on demand, instead of writing the same HTML over and over again:

```js
var out = document.getElementById("output");
var guestCount = document.getElementById("guestCount");
guestCount.addEventListener("change", makeGuests);

function makeGuests(){

  out.innerHTML = ""; // Clear previous output
  
  // Set up arrays that hold data that the two guest form lists need:
  var meals = ["Meal Choice", "Buffet", "Gluten Free", "Dairy Free", "Vegan"];
  var ages = ["Age", "Adult", "Child under 5", "Child 6 - 12"];

  // Create a loop that iterates the numnber of times specified in the list
  for(var i = 0; i < guestCount.value; i++){
  
    // Create and configure a guest form, element by element...
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    
    var heading = document.createElement("h4");
    heading.textContent = "Guest " + (i + 1);
    container.appendChild(heading); // Put new element in container
    
    var txtName = document.createElement("input");
    txtName.type = "text"
    txtName.placeholder = "Name";
    txtName.name = "name";
    container.appendChild(txtName);
    
    var mealList = document.createElement("select");
    mealList.id = "guest" + (i + 1) + "_meal" ;
    // Loop through the meals array
    meals.forEach(function(value){
      // And, create an option for each one
      var opt = document.createElement("option");
      opt.textContent = value;
      mealList.appendChild(opt);
    });
    container.appendChild(mealList);
  
    var ageList = document.createElement("select");
    ageList.id = "guest" + (i + 1) + "_age" ;
    ages.forEach(function(value){
      var opt = document.createElement("option");
      opt.textContent = value;
      ageList.appendChild(opt);
    }); 
    container.appendChild(ageList);
  
    // Make final input
    var allergies = document.createElement("input");
    allergies.type = "text"
    allergies.placeholder = "Allergies?";
    container.appendChild(allergies);
  
    // Everything is made and in the container. Add the container to the document
    out.appendChild(container);
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<h4>Number of Guests</h4>
<select id="guestCount">
  <option>Select number of guests</option>
  <option id="guestCountOne">1</option>
  <option id="guestCountTwo">2</option>
  <option id="guestCountThree">3</option>
  <option id="guestCountFour">4</option>
  <option id="guestCountFive">5</option>
  <option id="guestCountSix">6</option>
</select>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Think a little different. And use following stratergy.

Hide all `div` first.

1. Give id to `div` like `guestForm1`, `guestForm2` etc.
2. Pass id of dropdown to javascript and get its selected value
3. Loop from the `selectedValue` as integer to 1 (or opposite) and find `div` with `id=‘guestForm’+loopIndex`.
4. Make that div `display block`.

I can try to put some code together for this as example

**Example**

```
<select onchange='showForms(this)'>
<option value='0'>None</option>
 <option value='1'>1</option>
 <option value='2'>2</option>
 <option value='3'>3</option>
 <option value='4'>4</option>
 <option value='5'>5</option>
 <option value='6'>6</option>
</select>



<div id='guestForm1' style='display:none'>11</div>
<div id='guestForm2' style='display:none'>22</div>
<div id='guestForm3' style='display:none'>33</div>
<div id='guestForm4' style='display:none'>44</div>
<div id='guestForm5' style='display:none'>55</div>
<div id='guestForm6' style='display:none'>66</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function showForms(dd)
{

    var ddVal=dd[dd.selectedIndex].value;

  for(i=1;i<=6;i++)
  {
     document.getElementById('guestForm'+i).style.display='none';
  }


  for(i=1;i<=ddVal;i++)
  {
     document.getElementById('guestForm'+i).style.display='block';
  }
}
```

> Note, you still should add null checks, if div with certain id does not exist

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to start building an application. The following demo builds an application that does 2 jobs and is designed for expansion for additional functions if and when needed.

- Listens for the click event on `form#fX`.
- When clicked, it delegates the event between 2 buttons and ignores any other clicks.
- The first job it does is generate a `<fieldset>` for each guest from a `<template>`. The number of guests is determined by the user input of `input[type="number"]#qty`. At this point, the `input[type="submit"]` button is revealed.
- The second job is to submit the form data to a server. At this point a message is displayed informing user that the data has been sent and provides a link.
- The link scrolls to `iframe#view` which displays the server's response.
- This demo can do an unlimited amount of guests and each guest has a unique `#id` and all of its children nodes have unique `[name]` attributes.

**Note:** This demo sends data to a **[live test server](https://httpbin.org)**.

#### References

[**Event Delegation**](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)

[**HTMLFormControlsCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)

[**Template Literals**](https://css-tricks.com/template-literals/)

[**<template> tag**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)

#### Demo

```js
var idx = 0;
var fX = document.forms.fX;
var Xf = fX.elements;

fX.addEventListener('click', delegateClick, false);

function delegateClick(e) {
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
    if (e.target.value === 'Process') {
      var qty = Xf.qty.valueAsNumber;
      idx = generateGuest(qty, idx);
      e.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = "inline-block";
    } else if (e.target.type === 'submit') {
      e.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";
      Xf.msg.innerHTML = `Data sent. <a href='#view'>View response.</a>`;
    } else {
      return;
    }
  } else {
    return;
  }
}

function generateGuest(qty, idx) {
  var allx = idx + qty;
  for (idx; idx < allx; idx++) {
    var temp = document.getElementById('tmp');
    var cont = temp.content.getElementById('guest');
    var dupe = document.importNode(cont, true);
    var fset = Array.from(dupe.querySelectorAll('*'));
    dupe.id = `guest${idx}`;
    dupe.name = dupe.id;
    fset.map(function(node, index, fset) {
      fset[0].textContent = `Guest ${idx}`;
      fset[1].name = `nam${idx}`;
      fset[2].name = `eat${idx}`;
      fset[8].name = `med${idx}`;
      fset[9].name = `age${idx}`;
    });
    fX.appendChild(dupe);
  }
  return idx;
}
```

```css
html {
  font: 400 16px/1.5 Consolas
}

fieldset {
  width: 65%
}

select,
input,
button,
output {
  font: inherit;
  display: inline-block
}

select,
input[type="text"] {
  width: 45%
}

select {
  padding: 4px
}

#qty {
  width: 5ch
}

input:not([type="text"]) {
  font-variant: small-caps
}

input[type="submit"],
#msg {
  display: none
}

#view {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<form id='fX' action='https://httpbin.org/post' method='post' target='view'>

  <fieldset id='set'>
    <legend>Guest Register</legend>
    <input id='qty' type='number' min='1' max='99' value='1'>
    <input type='button' value='Process'>
    <input type='Submit'>
    <output id='msg'></output>
  </fieldset>
  <hr>
  <template id='tmp'>

  <fieldset id='guest' name='guest'>
    <legend>Guest&nbsp;</legend>
    <input name='nam' type="text" placeholder="Name">
    <select name='eat'>
   <option default>Diet</option>
   <option value='norm'>Buffet</option>
   <option value='tran'>Gluten Free</option>
   <option value='lact'>Dairy Free</option>
   <option value='vege'>Vegan</option>
  </select>
    <input name='med' type="text" placeholder="Allergies">
    <select name='age'>
   <option default>Age</option>
   <option value='18'>Adult</option>
   <option value='05'>Child under 5</option>
   <option value='12'>Child 6 - 12</option>
  </select>
  </fieldset>

  </template>

</form>

<iframe src='about:blank;' id='view' name='view' width='75%' height='75%' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```