# How to get array name from json encode to javascript on console.log?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have an array. I converted php array inside JavaScript. I want to get array's name for my select option. How to get array name on console log?

My code is below;

```
<script> 
var users= <?php echo json_encode($users) ?>;
        console.log(users);
</script>
```

[{0: {id:1, name: Alex, email: alex@gmail.com}},

{1: {id:2, name: Jane, email: jane@gmail.com}}]

This is what I get.

But this is what I want.

Alex

Jane

Can you help me please ?

Comment: If you only want the name attribute, you can use `Array.map()` to only return that attribute.

Comment: I put array names to select option. But this is the result:                                                 Alex, Jane                                                                                                                          Alex, Jane   But I want like this. Alex Jane (per option must have one name)

Comment: So just loop through the data and get those specific properties. Or use a map technique like one of the examples below. Unclear what the problem is. have you tried anything?

Comment: But...where are you generating the select? Doesn't your blade view generate and populate this from a model, if it's Laravel? Not clear why you're diverting the data to JavaScript first.

Comment: var users= <?php echo json_encode($users) ?>;
 var x = users.map(function(item) {
 return Object.values(item)[1]
       })  ///////////(I put name to option code below)              var userList = document.createElement("select");
        userList .id = "guest" + (i + 1) + "_age";
        users.forEach(function(value) {
       var opt = document.createElement("option");
               opt.textContent = x;
               userList.appendChild(opt);
           });
           container2.appendChild(ageList);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48967118/show-hide-multiple-divs-based-on-dropdown-selection-javascript/48967195#48967195  (I use this answer)

Answer (score 2):

You got use flatMap()

```js
const users = [{0: {id:1, name: "Alex", email: "alex@gmail.com"}},{1: {id:2, name: "Jane", email: "jane@gmail.com"}}]

const parsedUsers = users.flatMap(user=>Object.values(user));

parsedUsers.forEach(user=>console.log(user.name));
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use **@json** blade directive :

```
<script> 
var users= @json($users);
        console.log(users);
</script>
```